# How to format date (with letters) into numerical numbers in SAS?

Tags: format, sas

I have a data set that looks something like this:

```
    Name  birth  birth_day  death  death_day   
    Don   1913   02-Mar     1998   01-Nov
    Jack  1924   04-Dec     1970   13-Sep
```

I want to calculate the age of the people but I am confused as to how to format the entries in `birth_day` and `death_day` numerically so that I can subtract their birthdays from their death days to calculate their age. My professor suggested using the `dmy` function, so I did

```
    x=dmy(day(birth_day), month(birth_day), birth);
```

However that did not work as planned. How can I go about resolving this problem?

In response to rambles:

```
     data _null_;
     set mydata;

     death_date = input(cats(death_day,'-', death), date11.);
     birth_date = input(cats(birth_day,'-', birth), date11.);
     format death_date birth_date date11. age 4.1;

     age = yrdif(birth_date, death_date,'AGE');  ** The 'AGE' part only works in SAS 9.3+!!;
     put death_date= birth_date= age=;
     run;
```

I tried something like this, however I ge an error at the line `format death_date birth_date date11. age 4.1;` saying ERROR 48-59: The format $DATE was not found or could not be loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following example mimics your first row:-

```
   data example;
     Name = "Don";
     birth_day = "02-Mar";
     birth = "1913";
     death_day = "01-Nov";
     death = "1998";
   run;

   data example_with_age;
     set example;
     length death_date birth_date 5 age 3;
     format death_date birth_date date11. age 4.1;

     death_date = input(cats(death_day,'-', death), date11.);
     birth_date = input(cats(birth_day,'-', birth), date11.);

     age = yrdif(birth_date, death_date,'AGE');  ** The 'AGE' part only works in SAS 9.3+!!;
   run;
```

I've assumed your birth and death variables are character.  If they're numeric, you should surround them with a `put` statement in the `input` rows.

I've been lazy with calcalating age by using a feature in newer versions of SAS - it's a surprising hassle calculating age when using full dates.  If you're using an older SAS version, let me know in a comment and I'll add the older method of calculating the age.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So if I wanted to calculate the age for both Don and Jack in my example dataset (i.e., I want to calculate multiple ages) how would I do that?

Comment: I added more details in my original post, so if you could refer to that above, that'd be great. @rambles

Comment: I've changed my code to separate the example from the 'solution'.  Let me know if you still get the error when running the 2nd datastep.  Also, what version of SAS are you using?